# How to query the SerializerMethodField in list API view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `PhysicalServerListSerializer`, in it I have a `server_status` serializer method field.

```
class PhysicalServerListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    server_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = PhysicalServer
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1

    def get_server_status(self, obj):

        if obj.task and obj.is_finish_task:
            return 'ok'

        if obj.task and not obj.is_finish_task:
            return 'ing'
```

But I have a requirement, when I query it in the get method.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalserver/list/?server_status=ing
```

it can not query out the `server_status`, how to solve this issue?

---

My ListAPIView code is bellow:

```
class PhysicalServerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerListSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    pagination_class = CommonPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
                   for key, value in query_params.items()
                   }
        qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(**filters)
        return qs
```

Comment: It's a common practice to implement filtering on the view level. Can you also post your view code?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I have post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `server_status` is not model's field you cannot filter by it's value directly. But isntead you can update your query like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_params = self.request.query_params
    filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
               for key, value in query_params.items()
               }
    server_status = query_params.get('server_status')
    if server_status: 
         if server_status == 'ok':
             filters.update({'task__isnull': False, 'is_finish_task': True})        
         if server_status == 'ing':
             filters.update({'task__isnull': False, 'is_finish_task': False})        
    qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(**filters)
    return qs
```

Also I suggest you to use [`django-filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/rest_framework.html). This tool allows you to implement filtering much easier. Note however even with django-filter you will not able to implement filtering by `server_status` without `FilterSet's` customization.

Comment: BTW, may I ask you a question about will the `filter(xxx).filter(xxx)` affect the performance than use one?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 no, this will not affect performance. Even in this case you get only one DB query. Check this part of the docs for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Also related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy